# How to check answers of questions that are randomly generated using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ssms

I'm creating a quiz using C# windows form which randomly outputs questions from a table in server management studio. As the questions are randomly generated I'm struggling to check whether the answer inputted is correct from data in the table.

I've used Newid() to randomly generate the questions (i will show this below) but am now struggling to choose the answer as the way that I had previously searched for the answer would be dependent on the QuestionID.

This is the sql statement that I used to output the 15 questions

```
SELECT TOP 15  Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD 
FROM   dbo.Questions 
WHERE  AsOrALevel =1 
ORDER BY newid() ;
```

This is how I previously checked the answer submitted with the corresponding answer in the table

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlCommand checkQuestion1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Questions where Answer =@Q1 and QuestionID = @num ", con);
//("@QuestionNumber", QuestionNumber);
checkQuestion1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q1", Q1Txt.Text);
checkQuestion1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", num);

con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(checkQuestion1);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adpt.Fill(ds);
using (SqlDataReader re = checkQuestion1.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (re.Read())
    {
        RunningScore++;
        CurrentPercentage = CurrentPercentage + 6.66;
    }
    con.Close();
    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
}
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: `6.66`? Were you sent here by the devil, or is that a magic constant that ought to be calculated based on the number of questions instead? (Cumulative additions like this are subject to rounding errors; you're better off re-calculating the percentage from the totals when it's required.)

Comment: I must be missing something. Just add `Question_Id` to your select statement and use that to look up the answer. In fact it's much easer to also select the answer at the same time as the question then check it directly in your returned local recordset rather than going back and checking the db again

Comment: Ahhh that seems quite simple enough, would "select * from Questions where Answer =@Q1 and QuestionID = QuestionID " the correct statement?

Comment: To get the question and answer in one go you also add the answer the list of columns returned. i.e. `SELECT Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, Answer`. Then in your code you see if they picked the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Question_Id to your select statement and use this to look up the correct answers.